# What's wrong on inheritance template?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Here's my [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e170633f283c1bb0):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Plot {
    float test;
    
    Plot() : test(1.0f) {
    }
};

template <class T>
struct PlotTest : Plot {
    T *pModule;
    
    PlotTest(T *module) : Plot(), pModule(module) {

    }
};

template <class T>
struct PlotTestCustom : PlotTest<T> {
    PlotTestCustom(T *module) : PlotTest<T>(module) {
        test = 2.0f;
    }
};

int main()
{

}
```

But when I compile, it seems that `PlotTestCustom` can't see the `float test;` variable (which is on the "main" parent).

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I suggest changing the title to something along "Why public base class member cannot be accessed in a template?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During name lookup with template, it won't look at the base class (there could be a specialization of `PlotTest` that does not inherit from `Plot` for instance).

Thus you will have to give the compiler a hint:

```
PlotTestCustom(T *module) : PlotTest<T>(module) {
    this->test = 2.0f;
}
```

It means delay lookup until instantiation by making it a dependent name.

Full example here:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Plot {
    float test;
    
    Plot() : test(1.0f) {
    }
};

template <class T>
struct PlotTest : Plot {
    T *pModule;
    
    PlotTest(T *module) : Plot(), pModule(module) {
        test = 3.0; // accessible Plot is not a dependent base class
    }
};

// specialization that does not inherit
template<>
struct PlotTest<int> {
};

template <class T>
struct PlotTestCustom : PlotTest<T> {
    PlotTestCustom(T *module) : PlotTest<T>(module) {
        this->test = 2.0f;
    }
};

int main()
{
    double d{};
    int i{};
    PlotTestCustom<double> p1{&d};
    //PlotTestCustom<int> p2{&i}; -> does not compile
}
```

Comment: But within `PlotTest` I can access to it without `this`. Why?

Comment: "there could be a specialization of PlotTest that does not inherit from Plot for instance" uhm? `PlotTest` will always inherit from `Plot`: `struct PlotTest : Plot`

Comment: @markzzz non dependent name are not lookup in dependent base class but `Plot` is not a dependent base class

Comment: @markzzz see this example: https://godbolt.org/z/csvq9n

Comment: @markzzz add a theoretical `template <> struct PlotTest<int> {};` and that is not true anymore.

Comment: @markzzz I updated my answer by the way

Comment: Now is clear! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`test` is not a dependent name here, so you have to access it through `this` pointer thus deferring actual lookup until the template parameter is known

[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a3074acc563bc5d)

Answer (score 1):

You have to give compiler a hint, in what part of your object this member can be found:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct PlotTestCustom : PlotTest<T> {
    PlotTestCustom(T *module) : PlotTest<T>(module) {
        Plot::test = 2.0f;
    }
};
```